# laravel 4 create module and put controller , module and view inside module

Tags: php, laravel, url-rewriting, laravel-4, routes

I have worked on yii framework before and I had possibility to create module folder and inside this put eg: news module which was included **controllers, views and module**

I'm new in laravel and trying to create same thing **MODULE**

i tried the following inside routing

```
Route::get('/news','/modules/news/controllers/NewsController@index');
```

file exist but i'm getting

```
ReflectionException
Class /modules/news/controllers/NewsController does not exist
```

why ? what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Route::get()` function is looking for a (auto)loaded Class, not for a file on the disk to load, which is why you're getting these errors.

It's more Laravely (*Laravelish?*) to include:

- Controllers in the `/app/controllers/` directory
- Views in `/app/views/` directory
- Models in the `/app/models/` directory

And if you are starting out with Laravel, this might be the best way to get started.  The autoloader knows where to look for your classes then, and everything gets handled automatically for you.

With the `NewsController` situated in `/app/controllers/` you can do this:

```
// no need to start the route location with a slash:
Route::get('news', array('uses' => 'NewsController@index'));
```

You can "package" up functionality using [Laravel's Packages](http://laravel.com/docs/packages#introduction), but it would be better to check out the excellent docs and then come back with specific questions..

Comment: how access controller from  modules ?

Answer (score 2):

Put your Laravel controllers in app/controllers, since that directory gets autoloaded, and it is where Laravel expects controllers to be.

Then you can use routes like this (example straight from the docs at http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#basic-controllers)

```
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@showProfile');
```